# How to change a PDF's title? (not file name)

Tags: macos, finder, software-recommendation, pdf, adobe

My question is in reference to the title shown in Acrobat Reader's tab **and** title bar that reads "Modern business letter."

[image]

I generated the PDF from a .docx document, and the document is generated based on a LibreOffice template (.odt) named "Modern business letter", which is where the title name comes from.

I know how to change the template name in LibreOffice, but that can cause unwanted error if I forget to change it the next time I use the same template. Im looking for other macOS options so I don’t have to struggle in LibreOffice.

How do I change the individual PDF title, either in Acrobat Reader or in Finder?

Comment: Just to clarify, was the PDF itself generated by MS Word, or by LibreOffice? Also, what version of macOS are you running and what version of Acrobat Reader, MS Word and/or Libre Office?

Comment: @Monomeeth, Personally, I wish every question included the hardware and software information surrounding the question, however... There is no clarification necessary since neither Adobe Reader or Finder, by default and natively, have the capability to edit that information and that's the focus of the question being asked, "_How do I change the individual PDF title, either in Acrobat Reader or in Finder?_". the information you're requesting is not really relevant in this situation. It either needs to be done before being exported/printed to PDF or use an app capable of editing PDF Documents.

Comment: You cannot either in Reader or Finder...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To answer the question you asked, "*How do I change the individual PDF title, either in Acrobat Reader or in Finder?*", you can't. Neither Acrobat Reader or Finder, by default and natively, have the capability to edit that information. It needs to be done before being exported/printed to PDF or use an app capable of editing PDF Documents.

The industry standard is [Adobe Acrobat](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat.html) however it's an expensive app and overkill if looking to just edit that information.

---

If you have [`exiftool`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) installed and want to do it from the command line in Terminal, use the following syntax:

```
exiftool -Title="New Title" /path/to/filename.pdf
```

- To clear the Title, just use: `-Title=""`
- Other *meta-data* can be changed in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks for this! I also realized that this is the only method that does not change the size of the document. Before exiftool I tried several other methods (PDF Attributes and PDF Attributes Editor apps, Automator Workflow as described by @Allan below) but they all drastically increase the file size.

Comment: exiftool is the best answer, also the link to PDFInfo now houses a suspended page

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu as well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can do this through Automator.  Automator includes a number of functions to `get` and `set` `PDF Metadata` including things like "Title."

#### Super Simple:  Create a Workflow Application...

1. Create a new Workflow Application
2. Choose Set PDF Metadata (under the *PDFs* library)
3. Save; when you drop your PDF on the file, it will change the title for you.

[image]

#### More Steps, More Flexibility

The downside to that method is that while really simple, you can't programmatically change the Title (for whatever reason, you can't use variables in `Set PDF Metadata`).  It's great for batches if you wanted to change the Author or Keywords for a bunch of files.

So, to do this "sorta" programmatically, you have to do it *within* Automator

1. Create a new Blank Workflow
2. Choose *Get Specified Finder Items* (Under Files & Folders Library)
3. Choose *Set PDF Metadata* (Under PDFs library)
4. Drag and drop your PDF into the top box
5. Run
6. Rinse and repeat as necessary

[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about Automator and I usual do! Do you know what actual app the Automator Set PDF Metadata action is using to make the changes? +1 even if you don't. :)

Comment: @user3439894 - I don't know the actual app/library - I think it's just built into Automator

Comment: The reason I asked is `exiftool` doesn't contain any binaries and relies on `perl` (and the various perl libraries) to do it's thing. So in that respect I was wondering if Automator was using anything other then the primary _binary_ within the `/System/Library/Automator/Set PDF Metadata.action` file, which is the Set PDF Metadata _action_ you see in Automator itself, to do the actual work. As an example the Scale Images _action_ uses `/usr/bin/sips` to do that actual manipulation. So it's just idle curiosity if the Set PDF Metadata _action_ is calling an outside _binary_ to do the actual work.

Comment: Doesn't seem a way to use variables for the fields, has to be static text

Answer (score 13):

You don't need elaborate steps nor additional software for macOS to change Title. Following applies both for existing pdf file and file you are creating from .docx or whatnot. Just print to PDF (for existing pdf file one needs to create new one)

⌘ + P for printing and in opening printing window in the footer on the left side open drop-down menu and choose 'Save as PDF'.

[image]

It opens up Finder window for saving where you can set Title, Author, Subject, Keywords.

[image]

Comment: The question asks "How do I change the individual PDF title, either in Acrobat Reader or in Finder?"  Your answer is for a different question that is not asked here.

Comment: The question asks: "How to change a PDF's title? (not file name)". My answer addresses this question. I admit that in body there is also specifics referred but this has been already addressed in accepted answer. There are two questions - one in header and one in small print but my opinion is that this does not make first one to 'question not asked here'. Also, people landing on this thread with search term 'how to change pdf title' (2-nd result on my machine) expect to receive answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I found on a iMac, you must open the Word document first and go into File > Properties > Summary and you can edit the name of the Title and Author of the document there. Re-save the Word document. Re-Save as a PDF as normal.

When you open it in PDF, the tab will have the correct title.

Comment: What do you do if there is no Word document to start with?

Comment: OP has already mentioned they are aware of being able to edit the document properties before exporting to PDF (using LibreOffice instead of Word, but the same effect) — this question is specifically about editing a PDF after export.

Answer (score -1):

Open the pdf file in text editor (e.g. Notepad++) and search for the current title, then type new title instead. Save.

Example: I wanted to rename title of my pdf from "MergedFile" to "123456". I opened pdf in notepad++ and searched for "MergedFile". Found two instances and renamed both the "123456". Saved file. That's it.

Comment: Notepad++ is a Windows app.

Comment: To be fair, the question didn’t have good tags and clear requirements for macOS. I’ve edited that in since I can’t imagine someone would install a windows emulation or virtualization layer just to get notepad, but it’s fine for you to say that’s a good option and then this would be complete in my eyes. Maybe not up vote worthy, but a complete answer.

Comment: PDF files may contain binary data which will not survive a trip through a text editor. The assumption of a particular text encoding may also corrupt the file. The xref table may also become invalid.

Comment: Wow, so many salt here. I even provided Notepad++ just as an example, it's easy to figure what's your favourite text editor i guess.

Comment: As for the binary data, well, it worked for me w/a any issues. Afterall it's an easy, fast and no-cost solution so why not give it a try?
Anyways, just tried to help, will think twice next time ;)

Comment: worked great! ignore the haters

Comment: I tried this and it corrupted my .pdf file, so be careful and make sure you can undo or duplicate it before trying this.

Answer (score -1):

You may print the pdf into a pdf with typed a new title.